# Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask a question on how to use SolidWorks?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

After doing a search of the Stack Exchange sites, I couldn't find one for Engineers (Mechanical/Civil) using modeling software like SolidWorks.  I believe that this would be a very valuable site for a very large community.

If one exists, please direct me there.  Otherwise, please consider creating a new site for this expert audience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice, a fellow SW user :)

It's probably OK for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), their FAQ mentions "Computer Software";  however you're unlikely to get an answer there because there are few SolidWorks users on Super User.

There also is a beta [Engineering Stack Exchange site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). The site is relatively new, but there is a SolidWorks tag.

Answer (score 2):

The graphic design SE seems to have a SW tag:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks

But the SW forums are probably the best place:

https://forum.solidworks.com/welcome

Comment: I also think forum.solidworks.com is the best, as much as I'd like to have a Stack Exchange based forum, because of .... familiarity and great UI.